# Pass db values to modal box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I created a viewing module where a modal pops up when the user clicks the view button. For some reason it won't work when I click on the view button, nothing happens, basically.

Here's my fetch.php:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $output .= '<tr>
                <td>'.$row["req_date"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["reqname"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["natureofreq"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["postitle"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["critlevel"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["deadline"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["account"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["newaccname"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["lob"].'</td>
                <td>'.$row["site"].'</td>
                <td style="color:' . $colors[$row["status"]] . ';">' .$row["status"] . '</td>
                <td>
                    <form method="post" action="update-work-status.php">
                        <input type="hidden" name="reqnumber" value="'.$row['reqnumber'].'" />
                        <button class="fa fa-check" style="color: green" type="submit" name="approve" value=""></button><button class="fa fa-close" style="color: red" type="submit" name="decline" value=""></button>
                    </form>
                </td>
                <td><a href="records.php?reqnumber='.$row['reqnumber'] .'"><i class="fa fa-edit" style="color: black; font-size: 25px;"></i></a></td>
                <td><a href="#samstrover<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-warning"><span class="fa fa-pencil"></span> View</a></td>
                </tr>
                    <?php
                        require("viewdata.php");
                        $a++;
        ';
}
```

and here's the first line of my modal box (viewdata.php):

```
<div class="modal fade" id="samstrover<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

Please note that fetch is purely PHP, I just declare it on my HTML page using:

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Snippets will run only HTML/Javascript/CSS. Please don't use them for PHP. Thanks.

Comment: Notice that what you call "View Button" is only a link with no href or onclick event on it. The form that calls "update-work-status.php" is above. Also the code `<?php require("viewdata.php"); $a++;` is inside a string and aren't processed by PHP. It's just dumped in the page without further processing.

Comment: What do you think "View button" should do ?